How can I find emails where I was not explicitly listed in the to field?
I tried -to:me but that does not work. I can't figure out any combination of search options to find all emails that I got but were not explicitly sent to me.

try -to:full_email_address

That does not work. :/

That's weird can you add more info about your setup is it a free or Workspace account, do you have any aliases, send as addresses, anything forwarding. Confirm you are not including any spaces etc. -to:me works fine for me on the Web app as well as Android.
